# Nested Loop Calculation

Tags: mysql, nested

Okay so maybe this is way deeper than I will ever need to go however I want to be able to analyze this nested loop so that I can understand it.

Given:

```
mysql> describe t1;
+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| dt    | datetime | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And:

```
mysql> insert t1 values(101),(102),(103),(104),(105),(106),(107),(@c:=now());
Query OK, 8 rows affected (0.03 sec)
Records: 8  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

And:

```
mysql> insert t1 select @c:=@c+interval 1 second from t1,t1 b,t1 c,t1 d,t1 e,t1 f;
Query OK, 262144 rows affected (1.94 sec)
Records: 262144  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

So far I have the understanding that (#ofrows)^(#oftables)=(# of rows Added)

My question is why this is the case. I cannot find out exactly how MySQL is handling the rows and other system variables in order to create the equation that I have provided here. My equation is clearly a simplified version of the resulting action performed by the server as using 2 rows of data and 6  tables similarly gives an output of 64.

Does anyone know exactly how this is manipulated? I have been working on this for 2 days and I cannot get my mind off of it...

Also why is it inserting more than 6... maybe 36? rows into the table in the first place?? it is only specifying one possible select-able row from the tables and that is the previously inserted now() and then adding 1 second to that row and resetting the @c based on the final change so shouldn't it by logic only insert a few rows?

I guess to put it simply I understand what is happening specifically in the select @c:=@c+interval 1 second portion of the statement, but after that I am not quite sure...

I guess to put it simply how does:

```
select @c:=@c+interval 1 second;
+--------------------------+
| @c:=@c+interval 1 second |
+--------------------------+
| 2014-07-20 18:17:50      |
+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

turn into this:

```
...
Query OK, 262144 rows affected (1.94 sec) 
Records: 262144 Duplicates: 0 Warnings: 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer that was satisfactory for me on this issue was so simple I can't believe that I didn't realize it before now.

Today I needed to quickly fill a table with values so I decided to use another table that I had to do this. For example take table i which has the column i with values 1-50. I executed the following command to populate my table c column i.

`insert into c select i.i from i,i b;`

Based on my knowledge above I know that this would fill table c with exactly 2500 values. being that it executed the 50^2.

What I actually found that this was doing was examining each row from table i and multiplying it by the count of rows found in the first buffered instance `i b` and then inserting the resulting rows into the table. If you have more buffered instances it will get the results from one and then proceed to multiply those results further by the original 50 rows that would be found in the instance (for example `i c`).

I ended up with 50 rows of 1-50 within table c.

I didn't realize that this match based multiplication was being performed in this way before because I was using an incrementing operator and it would incrementally create new rows based on this multiplication, however it did not leave any indication that this is what it did due to the fact that it was not matching rows to duplicate rather it matched the number of rows to insert.